# save_an_open_page fails to work - error message indicates method not found - But why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, guard, spork

I posted this request under a different heading and received no feedback after I updated the request with information.

[save_and_open_page (capybara / launchy) stopped working in a project - error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608976/save-and-open-page-capybara-launchy-stopped-working-in-a-project-error)

I'm working on a private project where I am a single developer learning Rails and trying to do the right thing with using TDD/BDD, but this experience I have to say is making want to abandon the testing, as I simply do not have time to spend trying to fix environment issues.

I have spent the best part of 24 hours now trying to fix this. These are the things I have tried:

1. Deleted the Gemfile.lock and re-installed the bundle
2. Deleted the gemset and started from scratch
3. Followed the tutorial (M.Hartl's from scratch) to rebuild part of my environment

Last night --drb option was failing when I switched from my local project to starting to update some features on the git version for the master (As I'm still new with this I am running two projects and two git folders).

I have [`open_and_save_page`] working in the local project, but when I ran my specs to test all was well before embarking on the next phase of delivery I got failures relating to --drb, so I upgraded and that seemed to go away when I turned of the guard process.

Here is the current error:

```
imac:Genie railsdev$ rspec spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb --drb
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/Users/railsdev/Development/railsprojects/Genie/Genie/spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `save_and_open_page' for #<Class:0x007ff51d35a8a8> (NameError)
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
    from /Users/railsdev/Development/railsprojects/Genie/Genie/spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
    from /Users/railsdev/Development/railsprojects/Genie/Genie/spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
    from /Users/railsdev/Development/railsprojects/Genie/Genie/spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
    from /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
imac:Genie railsdev$
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.11.0"
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 1.2.1'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
  gem 'pickle'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.3.1'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'#,
                              #:git => 'git://bitbucket.org/railyboy/bootstrap-datepicker-rails.git' 
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'wicked_pdf'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

# Test gems on Macintosh OS X
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
#  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.4.3.1', :require => false
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', :git => 'git://github.com/ttilley/rb-fsevent.git', :branch => 'pre-compiled-gem-one-off'
gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
end 

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

The .rvmrc file

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125@genie-bb-v3-3 --create

which rvm => /Users/railsdev/.rvm/bin/rvm

rvm -v => rvm 1.16.8 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

The Guardfile:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

require 'active_support/core_ext'

guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')
  watch('test/test_helper.rb')
  watch('spec/support/')
end

guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_after_pass => false, :cli => '--drb' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }  
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$}) { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$}) { "spec" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { "spec" }  
  watch('config/routes.rb') { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb') { "spec/controllers" }
  # Capybara request specs 
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$}) { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$}) do |m|
    ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
     "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
     "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
     "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb",
     (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
                       "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
  end
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
    "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb"
  end

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }

end
```

The spec_helper.rb file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However,
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.

  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # ## Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
    # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
    # the seed, which is printed after each run.
    #     --seed 1234
    config.order = "random"
  end



end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

And the file the [`save_and_open_page`] is being called from:

```
require 'spec_helper'

# describe "AuthenticationPages" do
#   describe "GET /authentication_pages" do
#     it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
#       # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
#       get authentication_pages_index_path
#       response.status.should be(200)
#     end
#   end
# end

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "login page" do
    before { visit login_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Login') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Login') }
  end

  describe "login" do
    before { visit login_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Login" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Login') }
      it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { valid_login(user) }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      #it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Logout', href: logout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Login', href: login_path) }
      save_and_open_page
      # it { should have_content("[#{current_user}]") }

      describe "followed by logout" do
        before { click_link "Logout" }
        it { should have_link('Login') }
      end
    end
  end

...
end
```

I'm not sure if I am posting my questions in the right way as on some others I have not had any responses. Still new at all this and the help on here is immense. So thanks in advance.

What do I need to do to get this working on the second project?

One thing I did notice was since I started putting [`use`] in the .rvmrc file that I get the following when I cd into the directory.

```
Using /Users/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125 with gemset genie-bb-v3-3
Running /Users/railsdev/.rvm/hooks/after_cd_bundler
```

Is [`open_and_save_page`] a capybara method? Where does launchy fit into all of this? I thought it was a cucumber associated gem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this was a new user understanding error. I discovered that I could get this to work if I put the [`save_and_open_page`] within an `it` block.

I didn't see this in any of the documents that I read on this, but it makes sense I guess.

Comment: Just noticed save_and_open_page is not even present if you don't do a `visit ..._path` before, so calling it outside the block like this is certainly wrong