# Capybara skipping over a click_button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I have a test that fills out some fields and then is supposed to click a button. This is all done after loading up a modal window. However, it seems that it just skips over it and doesn't click the button. I have tried debugging it manually and calling it myself and it'll work fine but when I run the test by itself it doesn't click it.

```
Given /^I login with "(.*?)" and "(.*?)"$/ do |email, password|
  within "#signin_fields" do
    fill_in("custom_fields_email", :with => email)
    fill_in("custom_fields_password", :with => password)
  end
  click_button("Sign In") if page.should have_selector(".btn-signin")
end
```

I even added a check to make sure it was on the page but since the removal of wait_until, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to let the page load and then make sure it clicks the button properly. Any ideas would heavily appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a feedback?

Answer (score 0):

The following row from your code is incorrect as `have_selector` is a RSpec matcher:

```
click_button("Sign In") if page.should have_selector(".btn-signin")
```

Instead you should use any of [Capybara::Node::Matchers](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers) like:

```
click_button("Sign In") if page.has_selector?(".btn-signin")
```

Answer (score 0):

This post may help:  [How do you get rspec to output what it encountered rather than it "didn't find what it expected"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873016/how-do-you-get-rspec-to-output-what-it-encountered-rather-than-it-didnt-find-w/15874077#15874077) Basically, for debugging, you can add the line `save and open page` and inspect what the spec is finding and whether it differs from the results of your own debugging.

Answer (score -1):

page.should have_selector(".btn-signin") isn't going to return true or false and therefor the button will never be clicked. Just do this:

```
click_button(".btn-signin")
```

If it should be there then the test will fail if it doesn't appear on the page.

Comment: I had that originally, but it would just pass over it and never actually do what the button press was intended to do

Comment: What should happen after the user clicks the button?

Comment: Well if put a debugger after the click, the click would have not done anything but if I then call it manually, it'll work as intended. This leads me to believe the click works fine but that when the modal is loaded, Capybara for some reason is filling the form but hitting click_button, thinking it doesn't exist and skipping it.

Comment: If Capybara wasn't clicking the button then button then there would be an error. You say it seems to skip over it- does the next part of the test fail?

Comment: Yes, since the button click didn't actually go through, the next step, page.find("#profile_name").should have_content(student),
fails because the loggin in action which I am testing didn't actually get called.

Comment: I normally would of use wait_until in this kind of circumstance, but since it was removed, I'm left confused as to how to approach it

Comment: You can try adding in sleep(2.seconds) as a quick and easy fix.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27788/discussion-between-justneph-and-roberth)

Comment: [`click_button` accepts id, text or value as a parameter](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_button-instance_method). It doesn't support CSS selector. You should use `find('.btn-signin').click` instead